# symfony querybuilder and increase of sql request number

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository, query-builder

I made a `querybuilder` to get all the entities that I want into one request but at the end, it makes 26 sql requests.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you for any response/help.

Here is the query builder:

```
$builder = $this->createQueryBuilder("message")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:User", "user", "WITH", "message.sender = user.id")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:Thread", "thread", "WITH", "message.thread = thread.id")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:MessageMetadata", "messageMetadata", "WITH", "messageMetadata.message = message.id AND messageMetadata.participant != user.id")
;

$builder = $this->filterSoftdelete($builder, $user);

if($filters != null) {
    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        $builder->andWhere("(message.recipient = :id  AND user.firstname LIKE '%". $value ."%') OR 
                (message.recipient = :id  AND user.lastname LIKE '%". $value ."%') OR 
                (message.recipient = :id  AND thread.subject LIKE '%". $value ."%')")
            ->setParameter("id", $user->getId());;
    }
} else {
    $builder->andWhere("message.recipient = :id or message.sender = :id")
        ->setParameter("id", $user->getId());
}

if($ordering != null) {
    foreach ($ordering as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "subject") {
            $builder->addOrderBy("thread.subject", $value);
        } else if($key == "createdAt") {
            $builder->addOrderBy("message." . $key, $value);
        } else {
            $builder->addOrderBy("messageMetadata.isRead", "desc");
        }
    }
} else {
    $builder->addOrderBy("messageMetadata.isRead", "desc");
}

return $this->query($builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your builder should only fire one request. But maybe are you trying to access attribute or joined collections that are not fetched and lazy loading comes into play thus creating many unwanted requests.

Typically when in controller you fetch your entities using your builder :

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('myrepo')->myCustomQuery($myparams...);
```

Then you loop through your entities (maybe in twig) :

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $entity->getAssociation()->doSomething; // sometime here you forgot to fetch sayed association
}
```

The solution would be to use `->addSelect()`  in your query builder, which will force the selection and hydration of associated entities.

Basically you're doing :

```
SELECT entity.* FROM entity JOIN other_entity ON ...;
```

And doctrine, when needed fetch the missing other_entity resulting in unwanted queries.

But you should be doing :

```
SELECT entity.*, other_entity.* FROM entity JOIN other_entity ON ...;
```

You should use symfony toolbar to look at your request.

Hope this helps

Comment: WHen i do it, i've got another problem, like, wait for an Entity class, and gived an OtherEntity Class

Comment: in your $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder("message")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:User", "user", "WITH", "message.sender = user.id")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:Thread", "thread", "WITH", "message.thread = thread.id")
    ->innerJoin("AppBundle:MessageMetadata", "messageMetadata", "WITH", "messageMetadata.message = message.id AND messageMetadata.participant != user.id")
; you could add $builder-> addSelect('user')...

Comment: Thank you, i wil try it .in this case the innerjoin is ok but in other cases in my project, I need a leftjoin cause the are some records where the foreign key is null. there's no way to get it in one request with the query builder?

Comment: I am sorry but this is not a forum. Doctrine syntax is great because it allows you to factorize your queries. Moreover Doctrine will, in most cases, simplify your request. PS : you should use doctrine syntax for your queries, instead of mixing it with native bits.